# Когда PHP возвращает NaN?

Tags: php

Привет.Интересуют примеры когда идет возвращение этого типа
На просторах stackoverflow лишь нашел единственный пример:

```
var_dump(sqrt(-3));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acos(8)  в принципе nan это обозначает не число. Т.е. все операции которые связанные в числовыми операциями и не являются числом в понимании php. Скорее всего все что в комплексном пространстве

Comment: Наверно тоже поведение будет с логарифмами,степенями...